# Mapnik installation error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python, gcc, clang, scons

I am trying to install mapnik in ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine, following this tutorial https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation but when I enter `./configure` I am getting error like this

```
Inheriting from mapnik-settings.env
scons: *** SCons version 4.1.0 does not run under Python version 2.7.12.
Python >= 3.5 is required.
```

I have tried different methods but nothing is working. My gcc version is `gcc (GCC) 6.3.0` and clang version is `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)`.

Comment: The 16.04 LTS is EOL. But you may be interested in installing Mapnik as deb-package from universe pocket by `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libmapnik-dev` .

Comment: @N0rbert its not working..libmapnik-dev is already installed

Comment: Just looked: the configure script uses `PYTHON` as the interpreter if it's set, otherwise the thing named `python`. So if you can get a Python3 installed, and set the environment variable `PYTHON` to `python3` there's a chance it will work.  I suspect you're be chasing incompatibilities all throughout though - i.e. your 16.04 g++ may be too old for the current code, etc.

Comment: Hmm, the scons is bundled in with mapnik, and it's an old-ish scons (2.3) which shouldn't be making the complaint above (the version msg should have 2.3.0 in it if nothing else) - I had guessed the issue was that mapnik branch bundled a new scons. There's got to be something further fishy with how it's used - the invocation should pick up the right one:  `$PYTHON scons/scons.py ...`